# random number invocation from boost toolkit

Tags: visual-studio, boost, random, mt19937

Attempting to use the Boost toolkit on Windows 7, Vis Studio 2013.

I've successfully run their example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/random/example/random_demo.cpp)

There's a set of lines in the code:

```
// This is a typedef for a random number generator.
// Try boost::mt19937 or boost::ecuyer1988 instead of boost::minstd_rand
typedef boost::minstd_rand base_generator_type;
```

I comment out the typedef and replace with

```
typedef  boost::mt19937
```

exactly as the instruction says, but the problem is that the rest of the program doesn't recognize this.  I think they left off some instruction there.  Does anyone know what I need to do?

Addendum, the complete fix is this:
Step 1. Include the corresponding hpp:

```
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
```

Step 2. Use the correct typedef statement:
    typedef boost::mt19937 base_generator_type;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `<boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>` to use boost::mt19937

Comment: I did that.   Now I get a lot more errors ... added to the OP.

Comment: Ah...yea, that was part of the fix. I had the typedef incorrect as well.
Thanks, that's it.